# Mac OSX Lion mystery user account keeps showing up

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts

So I thought someone was coming into my office at night and maybe using my computer. Things were always out of place and lights on, etc.

So I disabled the Guest account I had on my computer and changed my password of the main account. A few days later, an "Other" account showed up on the home screen that I have absolutely no access to. It seems strange this account could even be set up if they don't have access to the main, but maybe they do...

How do I disable the "Other" account (it doesn't show up in the list of accounts in preferences), or how to tell if someone is gaining access to my main account?

Comment: Isn't it just the *Other…* entry on the login screen that indicates a hidden account? What is the output of `dscl . -ls /Users` on the command line? What sharing options are activated? Is there a file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in your home directory?

Answer (score 4):

The "Other" login account usually appears when your system is connected to a directory server, or the root user account is enabled.

To disable:

1. From the Apple menu choose System Preferences....
2. From the View menu choose Users & Groups.
3. Click on the lock and authenticate with an administrator account.
4. Click Login Options....
5. Click the "Edit..." or "Join..." button at the bottom right
6. Click the "Open Directory Utility..." button.
7. Click the lock in the Directory Utility window.
8. Enter an administrator account name and password, then click OK.
9. Choose Disable Root User from the Edit menu.

More Info: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528